# Tengo este error al usar los formatted strings

Tags: python

[image: python error al usar formatted strings en vscode]

Estoy usando python 3.7.3 en vscode, intente el mismo codigo en pycharm y funciona sin problemas, intente cambiando de ambiente virtual y tampoco funciono, hasta intente desinstalando vscode

Comment: Hola Felix, el error indica que casi seguro no estás usando Python 3.7.3 en vscode para ejecutar el código, sinno otra versión instalada en el sistema (Python < 3.6 / 2.x)... En principio tienes algo mal configurado. Si vas a la terminal (cmd) e ingresas `python` que intérprete te ejecuta?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, me sale esto 

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.557]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\fazog>python
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  4 2019, 01:37:19) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: Como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la guía solucione el problema simplemente desinstalando la version anterio de python que tenia, muchas gracias!